# Efficiently style Excel workbook or worksheets using IronXL

Tags: ironxl

We recently switched an Excel exporting app from PHP to C# and so switched libraries from PHPExcel to IronXL. The rendering performance has plummeted, mainly attributed to how slow IronXL is at handling cell/row styling. After benchmarking a variety of ways to style in IronXL, we discovered, somewhat counterintuitively, that it is faster to style row by row as you add rows then to add style-less rows then style the entire sheet at the end. Still, it is just very slow. For example, styling a sheet of about 10k records with these styles increases the export from 10 seconds sto over 2+ minutes.

```
row.Style.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
row.Style.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
row.Style.Indention = 1;
row.Style.WrapText = true;
```

We've done some SxS benchmarking of PHPExcel & IronXL using identical data and styling. Exports that take 10 seconds in PHPExcel takes over 3 minutes in IronXL.

Would greatly appreciate any tips on styling for efficiency in IronXL.